# Put list of values into several macro variables in SAS

Tags: sas

I have a list of values defined in a macro variable, e.g.,

```
%let datelist = 20100614 20120309 20151215;
```

Now, I want to put these values into the corresponding number of macro variables.  In this case, I want to put them into Date1, Date2, Date3.

Of course, I could manually type out:

```
%let Date1 = 20100614;
%let Date2 = 20120309;
%let Date3 = 20151215;
```

How can I do that in a dynamic way so that if there were 25 dates, or 2, it would still work?

Comment: This seems backward, how did they get into the list in the first place? Is there an easier way to go straight to the end?

Comment: Hmm, yes, you are correct.  +1.  There's some existing code that uses the current format and I'm not in control of that code.  So, I'm trying to use it so I don't have to recode all the dates manually.  But, your point is that if I had control, I could just define the different macros separately and then put them together into one datelist, if necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I'll suggest a data step, because I prefer that over macro loops any day. 
Use COUNTW() to count the number of loops required and use CALL SYMPUTX to create the macro variables. You should look into the third parameter of the function if you want to control the scope of the macro variable.

```
%let datelist = 20100614 20120309 20151215;

data _null_;
word = "&datelist";
n=countw(word);
do i=1 to n;
    call symputx('date'||Put(i, 8. -l), scan(word, i));
end;
run;

%put &date1.;
%put &date2.;
%put &date3.;
```